# Elseif in blade not working, laravel and blade (simple)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

```
@if($note->user->name->verified === false && $note->user->name->rejected === false)
    unchecked
@elseif($note->user->name->rejected === true && $note->user->name->verified === false)
    Rejected
@elseif($note->user->name->verified === true && $note->user->name->rejected=== false)
    Approved
@endif
```

I am trying to use this code above. However, it is just displaying nothing. This seems like a simple issue but i'm not too sure what is wrong.

Comment: What you mean by not working? You get error messages or the logic just don't give what you expected?

Comment: Can I see the result for `$note->user->name` please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not my business, but your code looks very bad.
Can you suggest some improvements?
Here they are
In your **Note** model

```
public function isRejected()
{
    return (bool) $this->user->name->rejected;
}

public function isVerified()
{
    return (bool) $this->user->name->verified;
}
```

then

```
@if( !$note->isVerified() && !$note-isRejected() )
    unchecked
@elseif( $note->isRejected() && !$note->isVerified() )
    Rejected
@elseif( $note->isVerified() && !$note->isRejected() )
    Approved
@endif
```

this code is much more cleaner and readable

Answer (score 0):

You may want to [type cast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) your model's attributes as boolean to use the identical comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try an alternative which is replacing `===` (identical operator) to `==` (equal operator). As suggested by @Malta, the problem you are facing might be caused by different datatype of both the variables you were comparing.

Ps: this might work but you cant check if both the variables have the same datatype.

Hope it helps =)